# Styling a QTabWidget to add a bottom border *only on the tab widget* does not work

Tags: qt

I am attempting to style a QTabWidget to modify the appearance of the tabs, and to add a blue border at the bottom.

when I set the `border-bottom` style for `QWidget`, a blue border appears on EVERY widget - including the one I want, the `QTabWidget`, but ALSO including all of the other widgets, which I do NOT want.  See this screenshot:

[image]

This seems promising, in that it seems all I need to do is set the `bottom-border` for the `QTabWidget`, rather than `QWidget` as a whole.  But, this does not work, as this screenshot shows:

[image]

Here is my complete stylesheet - it is set on the `QTabWidget` within Qt Designer:

```
QTabWidget {
border-bottom: 3px solid #3233ff;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected {
border-left: 1px solid #1c1515;
padding-left: 10px;
border-right: 1px solid #1c1515;
padding-right: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1515;
border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                 stop: 0 #ededed, stop: 0.7 #9898ff,
                                 stop: 0.9 #7e7fff, stop: 1.0 #3233ff);
 }

QTabBar::tab:!selected {
border-left: 1px solid #1c1515;
padding-left: 10px;
border-right: 1px solid #1c1515;
padding-right: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1515;
border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
margin-bottom: 2px;
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                 stop: 0 #e0e0e0, stop: 0.4 #dbdbdb,
                                 stop: 0.5 #d3d3d3, stop: 1.0 #cfcfcf);
 }
```

What must I do to get the blue bottom border to appear - but only for the QTabWidget?

Answer (score 1):

Use correct selectors: QTabWidget::pane

Comment: I tried various possibilities using `QTabWidget::pane`, and, sadly, none of them had the desired effect.  Other questions on StackOverflow and/or elsewhere indicated that a better approach was to use a `QWidget` selector (and then override in child widgets); this approach looked promising, as the screenshots indicate.  Nonetheless, in the meantime I have resolved the problem by subclassing `QTabWidget`, promoting the `QTabWidget` to this subclassed widget class, and calling `setDrawBase(false)` on its child `QTabBar` instance.

Comment: I can't say more that there: http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar

Comment: I played around with the examples at that link (and others) extensively before posting my question.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Hello, I happen to have a question similar to the one you posted here back in 2013 - perhaps you could have a look at it? Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64034628/qtabbar-styling-to-remove-a-bottom-border